# Solve this complex number: $z^2+(1+i)z+i=0$

Tags: complex-numbers, systems-of-equations, quadratics

I need to solve:

$$z^2+(1+i)z+i=0$$

first of all I used $$z = (a+ib)$$ and I get:

$$(a+ib)^2+(1+i)(a+ib)+i=0$$
$$a^2-b^2+2aib+a+ib+ia-b+i=0$$

then I have ordered, on the left the number without the $i$ and on the right all the number with the $i$:

$$\underbrace{a^2-b^2+a-b}_\text{real} + \underbrace{2aib+ib+ia+i}_\text{imaginary} = 0$$

So I have set this:

$$\begin{cases} a^2-b^2+a-b=0 \\ 2aib+ib+ia+i \end{cases}$$

$$\begin{cases} a(a+1)-b(b-1) = 0 \\ 2aib+ib+ia+i \end{cases}$$

How can I procede? I can say that the first equation is true when $a=b$

Comment: **Hint** We can factor the original quadratic readily, and this amounts to solving: What are two numbers whose sum is $1 + i$ and whose product is $i$?

Comment: Why not just use the quadratic formula? It's valid for complex numbers too!

Comment: Of course @Travias. Vietta's Theorem! Indeed it is easier than quadratic formula

Comment: @Travis: Don't you mean whose sum is $-(1+i)$?

Comment: @PM2Ring: I think Travis was looking for factors like $(z+\cdots)(z+\cdots)$ rather than roots

Comment: @PM2Ring What Henry said, but of course the problems are equivalent.

Comment: @Travis: Ah, ok. I'll pay that. :)

Comment: You might have a look at similar older posts, such as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1487813/how-to-solve-this-z2-1-3iz-2i-2-0 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1419221/find-solution-to-complex-equation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**hint**: $z^2 + (1+i)z + i = 0 \Rightarrow z^2+z + iz+i = 0\Rightarrow z(z+1) + i(z+1) = 0 \Rightarrow ...$

Answer (score 1):

The others pointed out a few ways how to guess the solution or derive the result for this specific case. However, the beauty of complex numbers is also, that math works on them just fine. So... just use the quadratic formula

$$z=\frac{-(1+i)\pm \sqrt{(1+i)^2-4i}}{2}=\frac{-(1+i)\pm \sqrt{-2i}}{2}$$
$$=\frac{-(1+i)\pm (1-i)}{2}=\{-i,-1\}$$
I used $\sqrt{-2i}=\sqrt{2e^{-i\pi/2}}=\sqrt{2}(\cos(-\pi/4),\sin(-\pi/4))=1-i$.

Answer (score 0):

Cool thing about complex polynomials is that they alwas have n solutions (where n is the order of the polynomial) and you can brute force it quite simply.
$$z^2 + (1+i)z + i = 0 \implies$$
$$(z+\frac{1+i}{2})^2 = -i - (1+i)^2 = -3i = 3e^{\frac{-\pi}{2}i}$$

Now you can take a square root to get:

$$z +\frac{1+i}{2} = \sqrt{3}e^{\frac{-\pi}{2}i \pm \pi i}$$

Simplify and solve.

Comment: I think you should have $(z+\frac{1+i}{2})^2 = -i + \left(\frac{1+i}{2}\right)^2 =  \left(\frac{1-i}{2}\right)^2$. Your completing the square is equivalent to the quadratic formula

Comment: You are right. my bad.